# Matlab object array to table (or struct array)

Tags: arrays, matlab, object, struct, matlab-table

Testing matlab2015a. I was using a struct array that at some point I converted to a table with `struct2table`. This gave a nice table with columns named as the fields of the struct.

Some time later and by unrelated reasons, these structs are now classes (or objects, not sure about the standard naming in matlab). `struct2table` rejects it; directly applying `table(objarray)` gives a one-column table with one object per row. I seem unable to find an `object2table` that does the obvious thing...

The closest I've come is `struct2table(arrayfun(@struct, objarray))`, which is a bit inelegant and spits a warning per array item. So, any nicer ideas?

Edit: example as follows

```
>> a.x=1; a.y=2; b.x=3; b.y=4;
>> struct2table([a;b])

ans = 

x    y
_    _

1    2
3    4
```

This is the original and desired behavior. Now create a file ab.m with contents

```
classdef ab; properties; x; y; end end
```

and execute

```
>> a=ab; a.x=1; a.y=2; b=ab; b.x=3; b.y=4;
```

trying to get a table without the arcane incantation gives you:

```
>> table([a;b])

ans = 

  Var1  
________

[1x1 ab]
[1x1 ab]

>> struct2table([a;b])
Error using struct2table (line 26)
S must be a scalar structure, or a structure array with one column
or one row.

>> object2table([a;b])
Undefined function or variable 'object2table'.
```

And the workaround:

```
>> struct2table(arrayfun(@struct, [a;b]))
Warning: Calling STRUCT on an object prevents the object from hiding
its implementation details and should thus be avoided. Use DISP or
DISPLAY to see the visible public details of an object. See 'help
struct' for more information. 
Warning: Calling STRUCT on an object prevents the object from hiding
its implementation details and should thus be avoided. Use DISP or
DISPLAY to see the visible public details of an object. See 'help
struct' for more information. 

ans = 

x    y
_    _

1    2
3    4
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your question, I am not sure if you really should convert an object to a table. Is there any advantage of a table?

Nevertheless, your approach using `struct` is basically right. I would just wrap it in a way it's easy to use and does not display a warning.

Wrap the functionallity in a class:

```
classdef tableconvertible; 
    methods
        function t=table(obj)
            w=warning('off','MATLAB:structOnObject');
            t=struct2table(arrayfun(@struct, obj));
            warning(w);
        end
    end 
end
```

And use it in your class:

```
classdef ab<tableconvertible; properties; x; y; end end
```

Usage:

```
table([a;b])
```

Comment: That's basically what I'm doing now, thanks. I'm converting in preparation for comfortable plotting and analysis with corrplot.

Comment: To address the warning rather than suppress it, combine the arrayfun logic with the approach shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48998022/1074263